# How to get the Properties of a *.mp3 File in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I´m programming a little media player with a song library.
Now I need to get the properties of a mp3,wma file, like the artist name or the song duration.

What is the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can examine the `ID3` tag of the mp3s. The [taglib-sharp](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.0.3.7/) library is great for doing so. Source code available ([here](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/)). Example code:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(pathtofile);
string artist = tagFile.Tag.FirstAlbumArtist;
string album = tagFile.Tag.Album;
string title = tagFile.Tag.Title;
...
```

Not sure if tag-lib supports .wma though... Tag-lib can however be ported to silverlight (if needed).

Comment: I´ve downloaded this ID3 library and added it to my project.

Comment: But It says that the AssemblyInfo.cs and the *.snk is missing. How do I fix that? Anyway this library is very effectiv and easy to use. Thank you for that hint.

Comment: How can I Length mp3 file . I use this :   ` string lengh = tagFile.Length.ToString();` but its return zero.????

Comment: Waren, if you delete the snk file, then open up the AssemblyInfo.cs file and delete these two lines,[assembly:AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFile("taglib-sharp.snk")]. This is of course respecting the original authors and only doing this for learning and not profit. Have fun.

Answer (score 4):

using an ID3 library. A quick google gave me: [csid3lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/)