# How to get a duration of mp3 file via .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

I need to create a M3U playlist of mp3 songs.

Is there any way to read the duration attribute of MP3 files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read metadata from mp3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369719/how-to-read-metadata-from-mp3)

Comment: Are we here to google for you or have you actually researched and tried something on your own?  In case you don't know about [this site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mp3%20c%23%20duration).

Comment: `Is there any way to read the duration attribute of MP3 files?`  **Yes!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve duration of MP3 in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net)

Answer (score 14):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an external library such as NAudio to do the hard work.

- [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) is available at GitHub.

You can use it like this:

```
Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader("<YourMP3>.mp3");
TimeSpan duration = reader.TotalTime;
```

Of course, an alternative would be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269914/4546874).

To use the `Mp3FileReader` class, you must add `using NAudio.Wave;` to your file.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone for help.

I tryed using TagLib and it works fine.

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(<pathToFile>, TagLib.ReadStyle.Average);
var duration = (int)f.Properties.Duration.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: There is a bug with TagLib's  duration properties. Most of the cases the actual time is only 70% of the taglibs duration

Comment: @StartCoding ~ Thanks for the warning. I decided to use `NReco.VideoInfo` instead. It wraps `ffprobe` from the `ffmpeg` toolbox. If one is doing much work with videos, `ffmpeg` is already in one's system path.