# Need to show the selected file's name in a label on WPF, not the full path

Tags: c#, wpf, label, filenames

I currently have an mp3 player in which a Label should show the name of the selected song. As I have it set right now it shows the full path to the song instead:

```
label1.Content = media.Source.ToString();
```

As the song can be selected there is no set location or filepath mentioned in the code, letting the user select a song from wherever they want.

I've tried media.Name.ToString(); but it only gave me the word "media", so Im probably missing something simple. Would like some help!

EDIT: Here's an example of what I want to see: "“TestMp3.mp3 is playing”"

Also would need to show "paused" or "stopped" when it is.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505870/how-to-get-the-properties-of-a-mp3-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: are you using the `System.IO` class at all.. ? if so you can use some of the `File and Path` functions to pull back the FileName property

Comment: Do you want to show the file name (as stated in the question title)? That could be done by [`Path.GetFileName(media.Source.ToString())`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx). Or the song title? Then see ffa's comment.

Comment: The file's name (which in this case is TestMp3) I dont know exctly where to put Path.GetFileName, as its meant to be shown inside a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only the file name instead of the full path, you may use

```
label1.Content = Path.GetFileName(media.Source.ToString());
```

using the static method [GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) of the class System.IO.Path.

This will return `test.mp3` from e.g. `C:\MyFiles\Audio\test.mp3`.

How to show if it is playing or paused depends highly on how you manage those states. Unfortunatly your question doesn't show what type `media` is of, so I don't know if the information is in there.

Comment: Woo! That solved the name part that's been driving me crazy, thanks! Now all I have to figure out is how to show whether it is playing, paused or stopped. media is a MediaElement type if thats of any importance.

Comment: @Sorez Sorry can't help you there. `MediaElement` doesn't seem to populate that, and I don't know what you are doing in the rest of your application. And for the sake of SO: this would be a totally different question than this one, so you may want to open a new question for that. It makes it easier to find for those who may answer as well as for others who have the same issues.